# Geometric Interpretation of the Gram-Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces

I wanted to ask what the geometric interpretation of the Gram-Matrix is. In our linear algebra course, we defined it as:

$$G(\vec{v_1}..\vec{v_n}) =
\begin{bmatrix}
\langle\vec{v_1},\vec{v_1}\rangle & \cdots & \langle\vec{v_n},\vec{v_1}\rangle \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\langle\vec{v_n},\vec{v_1}\rangle & \cdots & \langle\vec{v_n},\vec{v_n}\rangle \end{bmatrix}$$

Where $\vec{v_1}..\vec{v_n}$ are vectors in a vector space and $\langle\vec{v_n},\vec{v_n}\rangle$ is a dot product of two vectors.

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: The Gram determinant is the square of the volume of the parallelepiped determined by the vectors. Search for other answers on this site. Also my [video](https://youtu.be/IOrqUQscNOQ) may be helpful.

Comment: @blargoner This is exactly what I needed! Thank you very much. Could you maybe explain the importance of the gramian in linear regression (09:46 in the video)? Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

In 2 dimensions, the Gram matrix can be thought of as defining an ellipse (ignoring translation) or, equivalently, the [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) associated to a random vector with two components. This is also true in higher dimensions, but less easy to visualize.

[image]